# Flutter Page is not navigating to different page

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating a plants app with different plants cards in it. When click on card it will take you to the details page of that plant. But in my case page router is not working. I know i might have did a very dumb mistake but i am not able to find what i did wrong, i even tried to do console log(print as i'm using flutter) but the function is not returning anything. please help me.

```
import 'package:plants_app_ui/constants.dart';
import 'package:plants_app_ui/screens/details/components/details_screen.dart';

class RecomendedPlants extends StatelessWidget {
  const RecomendedPlants({
    Key? key,
    required this.size,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Size size;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          RecomendedPlantCard(
            size: size,
            country: 'India',
            image: 'assets/images/image_1.png',
            press: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(),
                ),
              );
            },
            price: 440,
            title: 'Alovera',
          ),
          RecomendedPlantCard(
            size: size,
            country: 'India',
            image: 'assets/images/image_2.png',
            press: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(),
                ),
              );
            },
            price: 440,
            title: 'Money Plant',
          ),
          RecomendedPlantCard(
            size: size,
            country: 'India',
            image: 'assets/images/image_3.png',
            press: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(),
                ),
              );
            },
            price: 440,
            title: 'Ujjwal',
          ),
          RecomendedPlantCard(
            size: size,
            country: 'India',
            image: 'assets/images/image_3.png',
            press: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(),
                ),
              );
            },
            price: 440,
            title: 'Ujjwal',
          ),
          RecomendedPlantCard(
            size: size,
            country: 'India',
            image: 'assets/images/image_1.png',
            press: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(),
                ),
              );
            },
            price: 440,
            title: 'Ujjwal',
          ),
          RecomendedPlantCard(
            size: size,
            country: 'India',
            image: 'assets/images/image_1.png',
            press: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(),
                ),
              );
            },
            price: 440,
            title: 'Ujjwal',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RecomendedPlantCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const RecomendedPlantCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.size,
    required this.image,
    required this.title,
    required this.country,
    required this.price,
    required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Size size;
  final String image, title, country;
  final int price;
  final Function()? press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: kDefaultPaddding,
        top: kDefaultPaddding / 2,
        bottom: kDefaultPaddding * 2.5,
      ),
      width: size.width * 0.35,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(image),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: press,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPaddding / 2),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    offset: Offset(0, 10),
                    blurRadius: 50,
                    color: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(0.23),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                          text: '$title\n'.toUpperCase(),
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
                        ),
                        TextSpan(
                          text: '$country'.toUpperCase(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Text(
                    '\$$price',
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .button!
                        .copyWith(color: kPrimaryColor),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your on gesture detector, use:

```
onTap: ()=>press()
```